# Django model validation in admin

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-admin

Similar to [clean() method in model and field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278753/clean-method-in-model-and-field-validation) and [Django: Validation error in Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967110/django-validation-error-in-admin) (although this one is old enough that it was answered before model validation existed)

I'm trying to use model validation in order to keep my code DRY, but I keep running into an odd error. My model looks like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class Period(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'nps'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.start > self.end:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Start date must be before end date"),
                code='invalid',
            )
        super(Period, self).clean()

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        conflicts = Period.objects.filter(
            start__lte=self.end,
            end__gte=self.start,
        )
        if any(conflicts):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Periods may not overlap."),
                code='invalid',
            )
        super(Period, self).validate_unique(exclude)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s - %s)" % (self.name, self.start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') or None, self.end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') or None)
```

When I try to save a model that's invalid (i.e. has a start date after the end date), instead of seeing a validation error on the admin page, I get the following exception:

```
AttributeError at /admin/nps/period/add/
'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_dict'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/nps/period/add/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_dict'
Exception Location: /opt/django_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in _update_errors, line 327
Python Executable:  /opt/django_venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/opt/webapp',
 '/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev',
 '/opt/webapp',
 '/vagrant',
 '/opt/webapp/C',
 '/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm 3.1.1/plugins/sass/lib/stubs/sass_functions.scss',
 '/Python27',
 '/opt/django_venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/django_venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/opt/django_venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/django_venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/opt/django_venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/django_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/webapp/webapp']
Server time:    Tue, 8 Apr 2014 16:29:24 -0400
```

It seems like the admin template is expecting something other than a `ValidationError` to be raised. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Django? The full stacktrace can be found here: https://gist.github.com/DBell-Feins/10170544

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and found a solution after some trial and error. I added the following in the `full_clean` method, but it should work elsewhere.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class User(models.Model):
    # ...
    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_username_slug()

        if User.objects.filter(username_slug=self.username_slug).exclude(id=self.id).exists():
            raise ValidationError({
                'username': [
                    ValidationError(
                        message='Username already exists',
                        code='unique',
                        params={},
                    )
                ]
            })
        super(User, self).full_clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

So in your case, you might want to have something like this.

```
class Period(models.Model):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.start > self.end:
            raise ValidationError({
                'start': [
                    ValidationError(
                        message=_("Start date must be before end date"),
                        code='invalid',
                        params={},
                    )
                ]
            })
        super(Period, self).clean()
```